# Ajax returns null

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have a problem with Ajax response. I'm trying to display a property address via specified ID number from mySql database. The problem I found is that, when I set the value of the id as static e.g `prop_id = 2`, then the address appears is successfully retrieved from db. But when I want to search by the *prop_id* entered in the text box I keep receiving null value.

**html**

```
       <td><label for="propertyId">Property Id:</label></td>
       <td><input name="p_propertyId" id="propertyId" onClick="suggestion_property_id()" onblur="get_property_address_byid()" size="40"></td> <!--onblur="get_idproperty()"-->
       <td><label for="prop_address">Property address:</label></td>
       <td><input name="p_address" id="prop_address" value="" size="40" readonly/></td>
```

**ajax**

```
    var $propertyId = $('#propertyId').val();
       //alert($propertyId);
       $.ajax({
                 type: 'POST',
                 url: 'propertyId.php',
                 data: {
                      type:'prop_address',
                      $propertyId:$propertyId,
                      },
                      async: true,
                      dataType: 'text',
                      success: function(res1){
                            var results = eval(res1);
                            document.getElementById('prop_address').value = results[0];
                            //get_idbooking();
                            alert($propertyId);
                            console.log(res1);
                     },
               }); 
            }
```

**php**

```
if($type == 'prop_address'){
       $prop_address = "no address";
       $propertyId =$_POST['propertyId'];
       $propertyId=155;          
       $properties = get_address_by_propertyid($propertyId);

       for($i=0; $i<sizeof($properties); $i++){
              $address_prop = str_replace(' ', ' ', $properties[$i]['prop_address']);
              if(strpos($propertyId, $address_prop) !== false){
                     $prop_address = $properties[$i]['propertyId'];
                     break;
              }
       }
       $res1 = array($address_prop, $propertyId);
       echo json_encode($res1);
       //echo json_encode($address);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your ajax block, you're passing across the `$propertyId` value as both name and value. So, if it's `155`, for example, your data block is effectively being sent to the server as:

```
data: {
    type: 'prop_address',
    155: 155
}
```

If you update the `data` block to name the `propertyId` parameter correctly, then your php script should pick it up.

```
data: {
    type: 'prop_address',
    propertyId: $propertyId
}
```

If you run in to these sort of issues in future (script works ok with value hard-coded but not when it's passed from elsewhere) a good place to start debugging is to have the php script `print_r($_POST)` or `var_dump($_POST)` to ensure you're passing across the parameters you think you are.

Answer (score 1):

The data that you are sending in the Ajax request seems to be wrong -

```
$propertyId:$propertyId,
^^^^^^^^^^^
```

should be -

```
propertyId:$propertyId,
```

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to heck the incoming data on the server side with, for example, `print_r($_POST)`. It looks like you are sending:

```
data: {
    type:'prop_address',
    $propertyId:$propertyId,
}
```

but checking for

```
$_POST['propertyId']
```

I don't think they match.

Answer (score 0):

You assign $propertyId to wrong key:

Should be:

```
...
data: {
    type:'prop_address',
    propertyId: $propertyId
    // $propertyId: $propertyId
 },
...
```